# Is there a legend for these 88 HST images?

Tags: hubble-telescope

Is there a legend for these 88 Hubble Space Telescope images?

[image: HubbleGallery.jpg - Hubble Space Telescope]

I have a 6000px x 4800 px version of this image (reduced & rotated to 480x600 here) that I use for an [image slide show](http://forums.aussievapers.com/club-vape-|-off-topic-discussion/31195-hubble-gallery-slide-show.html).  I would like to add the description of each image into the slide show software.

On this system the file name is `HubbleGallery.jpg` but I suspect I coined that title (it was a long time ago it was downloaded).  The original image is 5,150,779 bytes in size.

Searching on the smaller, rotated version of the image points to pages like [Astronomy Printshop](http://hubblesite.org/gallery/printshop/ps17/), but there is nothing closely related to NASA in the first pages of the search, and the pages listed did not have much detail (certainly no legend).

It might possible to search on the clipped, individual images, but I was hoping to avoid having to do that 88 times.

Comment: Where did you get the image from? Does it not have that information? You can almost certainly make life easier by identifying some of the pictures in the [Hubble Heritage gallery](http://heritage.stsci.edu/gallery/gallery.html). Then, for the remainder, I'd use image search on the individual clipped images.

Comment: @Warrick *"Where did you get the image from?"*  The internet (cannot remember where).  Since I cannot recall downloading it, it was likely more than 2 years ago. *"Does it not have that information?"*  Not that I could find then (I'd have saved the info. in a text file in the same location - as I commonly do), or can find now.  Don't get me wrong, this image occurs many times across the internet, but I could not locate it at NASA's site and none of the other sites had a legend for it.  -  See below for my attempt to identify the 88 images using image search.

Comment: Heh, I also have a lot of stuff in my download folder that I wouldn't be able to source again! Anyway, I tried an image search with your image, and immediately got this [this page](http://www.skyimagelab.com/hubphot.html), which links to [a page with separate entries for many of the images](http://www.skyimagelab.com/frehubwal.html), with descriptions. But I see you've answered it now anyway...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To answer my own question: no, not that I can find.

Here is an attempt to identify them by image search.  Let me know if there is an image/legend match that seems wrong.  I can upload a higher resolution (466x426 px) version of the image.

The images were cropped from the original image when it was oriented so the the 'HUBBLE SPACE TELESCOPE' message read from the bottom to top of image, and I will try to identify them in the same order.  As such, we do 1 column at a time from top to bottom, starting from the right most.  The column is marked in red above/below.

But first, here is the [captioned video](https://www.youtube.com/attribution_link?a=IIZIGoYF240&u=%2Fwatch%3Fv%3Ds33EBgtmkYA%26feature%3Dshare) created from combining the captions with a video slideshow of the images!

### Column 1

[image: spacer][image: spacer][image: spacer][image: spacer][image: spacer][image: spacer][image: spacer][image: marker]
[image]
[image: spacer][image: spacer][image: spacer][image: spacer][image: spacer][image: spacer][image: spacer][image: marker]

1. Gravitational lensing of distant galaxies.
2. Red Rectangle Nebula.
3. The Sombrero Galaxy: Messier 104.
4. Doradus Nebula.
5. Stingray Nebula.
6. Elliptical Galaxy NGC 4881 in Coma.
7. Galaxy NGC 4214.
8. Glowing Eye of NGC 6751.
9. Collection of galaxies of different types, from different ages in the universe.
10. Uranus: Springtime in the Southern Hemisphere.
11. The Lunar Aristarchus crater imaged using ultraviolet and visible wavelengths.

### Column 2

[image: spacer][image: spacer][image: spacer][image: spacer][image: spacer][image: spacer][image: marker]
[image]
[image: spacer][image: spacer][image: spacer][image: spacer][image: spacer][image: spacer][image: marker]

1. Supernova remnant N132D, in the Large Magellanic Cloud.
2. Ring Galaxy AM 0644-741.
3. Bug Nebula NGC 6302.
4. Planetary Nebula M2-9.
5. The Cone Nebula in NGC 2264.
6. Young planetary nebula MyCn18.
7. A stellar jet in the Trifid nebula.
8. Galaxy Pair NGC 3314. A face-on galaxy lying precisely in front of another spiral galaxy.
9. Comet LINEAR dispersing after breaking up.
10. A 5000 light year long jet from the giant elliptical galaxy M87.
11. The Massive Stars of 30 Doradus as seen in the star cluster R136.

### Column 3

[image: spacer][image: spacer][image: spacer][image: spacer][image: spacer][image: marker]
[image]
[image: spacer][image: spacer][image: spacer][image: spacer][image: spacer][image: marker]

1. NGC 346 is an open cluster with associated nebula located in the Small Magellanic Cloud.
2. The Cat's Eye Nebula or NGC 6543, is a relatively bright planetary nebula in the northern constellation of Draco.
3. This infrared view of Uranus reveals that the planet is surrounded by its four major rings and by 10 of its 17 known satellites.
4. Galaxy NGC 4013. An amazing \"edge-on\" view of a spiral galaxy 55 million light years from Earth.
5. The inner ring of NGC 1512.
6. Detail of the Omega Nebula.
7. This close-up of the red planet Mars was taken when it was just 55,760,220 km away.
8. Stellar Spire in the Eagle Nebula
9. Interacting galaxies NGC 1409 & 1410.
10. NGC 1850 - Star clusters in the Large Magellanic Cloud.
11. Io, Ganymede, and Callisto casting eclipse shadows on Jupiter.

### Column 4

[image: spacer][image: spacer][image: spacer][image: spacer][image: marker]
[image]
[image: spacer][image: spacer][image: spacer][image: spacer][image: marker]

1. Crab Nebula Mosaic
2. N44F's central star is wrapped within a roughly spherical shell of cool orange gas, with fingerlike columns of cool gas and dust protruding from the interior wall.
3. The Whirlpool Galaxy (M51) and companion galaxy.
4. Aurora at Jupiter's north pole as seen in ultraviolet light.
5. Bow shock near young star LL Ori.
6. The Black Eye Galaxy (also called Evil Eye Galaxy; designated Messier 64, M64, or NGC 4826)
7. A color-composite image of the Pleiades, or Seven Sisters (Messier 45 or M45), an open star cluster.
8. Orion nebula mozaic.
9. The Eskimo Nebula (NGC 2392).
10. Galaxy collision in NGC 6745.
11. Rich star fields and glowing hydrogen gas silhouette dense, opaque clouds of interstellar gas and dust in a bright star forming region in Centaurus

### Column 5

[image: spacer][image: spacer][image: spacer][image: marker]
[image]
[image: spacer][image: spacer][image: spacer][image: marker]

1. Aristarchus Plateau on the Moon.
2. The Tadpole Galaxy features a trail of stars about 280,000 light-years long and massive, bright blue star clusters.
3. Infant Stars in the Small Magellanic Cloud.
4. The Ghost-Head Nebula: NGC 2080.
5. The Pencil Nebula (NGC 2736) is a small part of the Vela Supernova Remnant, located near the Vela Pulsar in the constellation Vela.
6. Flash from star V838 Monocerotis echoes through space.
7. Rampaging Supernova Remnant N63A.
8. The center of globular cluster Omega Centauri.
9. The Bubble Nebula (NGC 7635), also called the Sharpless 162, or Caldwell 11, in the constellation Cassiopeia.
10. The center of NGC 4414, an unbarred spiral galaxy about 62 million light-years away in the constellation Coma Berenices.
11. NGC 3132, also known as the Eight-Burst Nebula, the Southern Ring Nebula, is a bright and extensively studied planetary nebula in the constellation Vela.

### Column 6

[image: spacer][image: spacer][image: marker]
[image]
[image: spacer][image: spacer][image: marker]

1. Messier 22 (also known as M22 or NGC 6656) is an elliptical globular cluster in the constellation Sagittarius, near the Galactic bulge region.
2. Star forming region N11B lies in the Large Magellanic Cloud.
3. The Homunculus Nebula is a bipolar reflection nebula surrounding the massive star system Eta Carinae.
4. Hoag's Object: a Ring Galaxy.  On the outside is a ring dominated by bright blue stars, while near the center lies a ball of much redder stars.
5. Detail of the Keyhole Nebula. The small nebula to the upper left has been nicknamed \"finger of God\" or \"God's birdie\", due to the gesture it appears to be making.
6. Reflection nebulosity near Merope (IC 349).
7. NGC 1569: Starburst in a small calaxy.
8. NGC 1300 is a barred spiral galaxy about 61 million light-years away in the constellation Eridanus.
9. The Lagoon Nebula
10. Planetary Nebula NGC 6543, the \"Cat's Eye Nebula\" is thought to have formed one one star of a double system went supernova.
11. NGC 1999 is a dust filled bright nebula with a vast hole of empty space represented by a black patch of sky.

### Column 7

[image: spacer][image: marker]
[image]
[image: spacer][image: marker]

1. This glowing region reveals arcs and bubbles formed when stellar winds - streams of charged particles ejected by the Trapezium stars - collide with material.
2. Auroras at Saturn's north and south poles.
3. Sheets of debris from a stellar explosion (N 49, DEM L 190).
4. The Horsehead Nebula.
5. The Retina Nebula: dying star IC 4406 has a doughnut shaped nebula seen edge on.
6. The center of NGC 1275 (also known as Perseus A or Caldwell 24), which is a type 1.5 Seyfert galaxy
7. NGC 4622 has bright twisting arms containing newborn stars and lies 111 million light years away.
8. Double Bubble' of gas and dust in the Large Magellanic Cloud.
9. Saturn displays its familiar banded structure, with haze and clouds at various altitudes.
10. Comet-like filaments along the inner rim of the Helix Nebula's gas ring.
11. Galactic nebula NGC 3603 shows various stages of the life cycle of stars.

### Column 8

[image: marker]
[image]
[image: marker]

1. Thousands of stars are forming in the cloud of gas and dust known as the Orion nebula.
2. A wheel galaxy around 500 million light-years from the Earth.
3. Stellar spire of the Eagle Nebula
4. The Circinus Spiral Galaxy
5. The Egg Nebula
6. Gaseous streamers flutter from a group of stars.
7. The Seyfert's Sextet.
8. Bubbly ocean of glowing hydrogen, oxygen, and sulphur gas in the extremely massive and luminous molecular nebula Messier 17.
9. North Eastern region of NGC 6369: The Little Ghost Nebula.
10. Double galaxies of NGC 4676 in collision.
11. Star clusters born among the interacting galaxies of Stephan's Quintet.